# Difference between my development app and production app

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, production

Why would my react app website in development look different after building it?  When running npm start my code runs fine.  However, when creating a build by running npm run build, some, not all, of my site text is off.  What gives?

I tried updating my media queries in my app.css file.
I tried running npm install to make sure I have all me dependencies.

Comment: You either have one of the pages zoomed in or path to css is wrong